# Updating Angular scope variables from $http.get call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fairly new to Angular, and I'm trying to figure out why scope variables isn't updating after they've been set.

I'm calling a Node API returing json objects containing my data. Everything seems to work fine except setting $scope.profile to the data returned from the API.

**Setup:**

app.js

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("gamedin", []);


  app.controller('profileController', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.profile = {};

    $scope.getProfile = function() {
      var vanityUrl = $scope.text.substr($scope.text.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

      $http.get('/steamid/' + vanityUrl)
      .then(function(data) {
        $http.get('/profile/' + data.data.response.steamid)
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data.data.response.players[0]); // Correct data
          $scope.profile = data.data.response.players[0]; // View isn't updated
        })
      })

      // Reset the input text
      $scope.text = "";
    }
  });

  ...

  app.directive('giHeader', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'components/header/template.html'
    };
  })

  app.directive('giProfile', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'components/profile/template.html'
    }
  })

})();
```

components/header/template.html

```
<header>
  <div class="header-content" ng-controller="profileController">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="header-content-inner">
        <input ng-model="text" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && getProfile()" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Steam URL">
      </div>
      <p>e.g., http://steamcommunity.com/id/verydankprofilelink</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

components/profile/template.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-controller="profileController">
    <h3> 
      <strong>Username: {{ profile.personaname }}</strong>
    </h3>
    <p> SteamID: {{ profile.steamid }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="gamedin">
<head>
  ...
</head>

<body>

  ...

  <gi-header></gi-header>

  <gi-profile></gi-profile>

  ...

</body>
</html>
```

---

I've tried wrapping it in $scope.$apply, like this

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
  $scope.profile = data.data.response.players[0];
});
```

... which resulted in `Error: [$rootScope:inprog]`

Then I tried

```
$timeout(function () {
  $scope.profile = data.data.response.players[0];
}, 0);
```

and

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function() { 
  $scope.profile = data.data.response.players[0]; 
});
```

... and although no errors were thrown, the view still wasn't updated.

I realize that I'm probably not understanding some aspects of angular correctly, so please enlighten me!

Comment: Which section do you expect to be updated? I don't see any reference to `profile` variable in the HTMLs. Are you talking about the directives?

Comment: Isn't there an issue with the property name "personaname"? Seems weird.

Comment: @OmriAharon: I want to update `components/profile/template.html` (that accesses the profile variable) when $scope.profile is updated.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 instances of `profileController`, one in each directive template. They should both share the same instance, because what happens now is that one instance updates `profile` variable on its scope, and the other is not aware. I.e., the `profileController` instance of header template is executing the call, and you expect to see the change on the profile template.

You need a  restructure. I suggest use the controller in the page that uses the directive, and share the profile object in both directives:

```
  <gi-header profile="profile"></gi-header>

  <gi-profile profile="profile"></gi-profile>
```

And in each directive:

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
     profile: '='
  },
  templateUrl: 'components/header/template.html'
};
```

And on a more general note - if you want to use a controller in a directive, you should probably use the directive's "controller" property.

Comment: @topic No problem :) Please try to mark the answers that solved your problem as "solved" (the check mark) so others will know you've found your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method instead:

```
$http.get('/steamid/' + vanityUrl)
  .then(function(data) {
    return $http.get('/profile/' + data.data.response.steamid).then(function(data) { 
      return data;
    });
  })
  .then(function(data) {
     $scope.profile = data.data.response.players[0]; // View isn't updated
  })
```

Where you use two resolves instead of one and then update the scope from the second resolve.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. I'm returning from a callback, that's why I chained it.

Comment: If you console log the data in the second resolve what do you get?

Comment: Then it should work as you expect, what if you wrap the `$scope.profile = data.data.response.players[0];` in a timeout?

Comment: Did you try it with my solution too or with the one you previously had?

Comment: Yeah, still nothing I'm afraid.

Comment: Odd, you can't create a plunkr? I've had this issue before and I solved it by doing the above, so it should work. Perhaps there is something else that's causing the issue.

Comment: Sure, does it need to include the back-end as well?

Comment: Preferably, so I can get an actual steam id when I hit enter